# Why does Alamofire returns access token with value null?

Tags: swift3, alamofire

The `accessToken` that is returned is `null`.

This is my code:

```
func commonNetworkCallWithHeader(completion:@escaping (String) -> Void)->String {

    var accessToken = "";

    Alamofire.request(apiUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseString { (response) in
        if(response.result.isSuccess) {
            if let jsonResponse = response.result.value {

                if let jsonTrial = jsonResponse.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                    let jsonConvert = JSON(data: jsonTrial)
                    accessToken = jsonConvert["access_token"].stringValue
                    completion(accessToken)
                    print("method:" + accessToken)
                }
            }
        }     
    }

    return accessToken
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be more specific what you are trying to do and what your problem is. Which API are you calling? What is the JSON the API returned? Also try to format your code properly to make it easier to read. In general: If you expect people to put effort into answering your questions you should put effort in your question.

Comment: First things first. Is `jsonConvert` nil?